# dependency error while adding firebase messaging to a flutter android project

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, google-cloud-messaging

I've added firebase messaging to my Flutter project.

Works fine on iOS, getting an error when trying to run on Android:

```
Android dependency 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

My configuration:

in pubspec.yaml

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.11.0+2
firebase_auth: ^0.11.1
firebase_messaging: ^5.0.1+1
```

in android/build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

in android/app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
```

in gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 2):

I fix the error using this [answer](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27254#issuecomment-461692152). You can work around it by adding the following lines next to other `subprojects` sections in `../android/build.gradle` (not `../android/app/build.grade`).

Thanks to [mklim](https://github.com/mklim) for the [solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27679#issuecomment-463438749).

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager' &&
                    !details.requested.name.contains('androidx')) {
                details.useVersion "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my version: `firebase_messaging: ^5.0.4`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer was found here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

followed this section: "Manually migrate your app", specifically step 2 helped to sort this out