# Android dependency 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, androidx

I was trying to add in app purchase package of flutter. which created the AndroidX migration issue first. Then after migrating I got another error which i have no clue to solve.

I didn't even write any code for in app purchase. Just after adding to pubspec.yaml its causing the problem.

The error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.                         
> Android dependency 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See goo.gl/CP92wY for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

pubspec.yaml dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http:
  cloud_firestore: 
  intl: ^0.15.8
  firebase_admob: 
  firebase_core:
  firebase_auth: 
  firebase_database: 
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  shared_preferences: 0.5.3+1 
  emoji_picker:
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1
  flutter_facebook_login:
  firebase_messaging: 
  image_picker_modern: ^0.4.12+2
  firebase_storage: 
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.0.1
  in_app_purchase: 0.1.0+1
```

Gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 2):

Original Link: [stackoverflow.com/a/56862428/7731547](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56862428/7731547%20%E2%80%93)

I fix the error using this answer. You can work around it by adding the following lines next to other subprojects sections in ../android/build.gradle (not ../android/app/build.grade).

Thanks to mklim for the solution.

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager' &&
                    !details.requested.name.contains('androidx')) {
                details.useVersion "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my version: firebase_messaging: ^5.0.4

Answer (score 1):

carefully follow these steps, had the same error. success!
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Comment: The app uses an AndroidX plugin and its main build.gradle file has a compileSdkVersion below version 28.  and follow the next steps https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#not-recommended-manually-migrate-your-app

Answer (score 0):

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
     ...
  }
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Write `resolutionStrategy.force` code in android/build.gradle file.

It will force android to use 1.0.0 version only.

Let me know if you didn't get me.